# How do I convert a hex array into a UIImage?

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimageview, bluetooth, uiimage

There are several unanswered questions related to printing images dynamically with P25mi, none with accepted answers. A couple links below.

[How to convert image to bitmap code for bluetooth print in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838283/how-to-convert-image-to-bitmap-code-for-bluetooth-print-in-iphone)

[How to convert image into hexa decimal bytes array to send it to output stream in iOS sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879807/how-to-convert-image-into-hexa-decimal-bytes-array-to-send-it-to-output-stream-i)

The code sample below is a hard-coded working example that prints a static image to p25mi. The first 10 elements in the array are control and format commands for the p25.

I think converting the hex array below into a UIImage displayable in a UIImageView might shed some light on doing the reverse.

How do I determine the height, width and depth of the image represented in the code sample below?

How do I convert the hex array below into a UIImage?

```
unsigned char buffer3[796]={
    0x55 ,  0x66 ,  0x77 ,  0x88 ,  0x44 ,  0x1B ,  0x58 ,  0x31 ,  
    0x19, 0x20, 
    0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03
    ,0xA0 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0xB0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0xD8 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0xA0 ,0x00 ,0x13 ,0xEC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x04 
    ,0x20 ,0x00 ,0x29 ,0xF4 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x64 ,0xF9 ,0x00
    ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0x7F ,0xF9 ,0xC0 ,0x3D ,0xFF
    ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF2 ,0x73 ,0x80 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0
    ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0x7F ,0xFD ,0xE0 ,0x3D ,0xFF ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x79 ,0x26 ,0xC0 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE
    ,0xFF ,0xFD ,0xF0 ,0x7D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xFF ,0xF7 ,0xFF ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x3C ,0x8F ,0x60
    ,0x0C ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF0 ,0x7D ,0x80
    ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x04 ,0x9E ,0x8F ,0xB0 ,0x0E ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0
    ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF8 ,0xFD ,0x80 ,0x33 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0
    ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0x4F ,0x27 ,0xD8 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC 
    ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF9 ,0xFD ,0xFF ,0xF3 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0x26 ,0x53 ,0xC8
    ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0xEF ,0xFD ,0xDD ,0xDD ,0xFF
    ,0xF3 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0x90 ,0xC9 ,0xF0 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0
    ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0xEF ,0xFD ,0xDF ,0x9D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0
    ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xC9 ,0xE4 ,0xE0 ,0x0C ,0x00 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x06 
    ,0xE7 ,0xFD ,0xCF ,0x9D ,0x80 ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xF0 ,0xF2 ,0x40
    ,0x0E ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x00 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xCF ,0x1D ,0x80
    ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xE6 ,0x79 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDF ,0xFC ,0xFF
    ,0xF9 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC7 ,0x1D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xFF ,0xF7 ,0xFF ,0xE0
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x49 ,0x3D ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9F ,0xFC ,0xFF ,0xF9 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE
    ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC2 ,0x1D ,0xFF ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1C ,0x9E ,0x00 
    ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x1F ,0xFC ,0x7F ,0xE1 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC0 ,0x1D ,0xFF
    ,0xE0 ,0xFF ,0xC1 ,0xFF ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0x4C ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0x20 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0x90 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
    ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00   
};
```

Comment: What format is this? `file` says `data` only.

Comment: from what I can tell after reviewing the documentation and this the link below. It's monochrome bmp. http://bluebamboo.helpserve.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [P25 Development Guide V3.4.1](http://bluebamboo.helpserve.com/Knowledgebase/Article/GetAttachment/27/8).

I don't understand what the first five characters are for. But the following characters are an esacpe sequence:

```
 0x1B,  0x58,  0x31,  0x19, 0x20
```

They are for printing a bit-image in horizontal mode. 0x19 and 0x20 are the horizontal dimension (times 8) and the vertical dimension, respectively. So the image is 200 by 32 pixel. The following 25 x 32 bytes then contain the pixels (black and white, 1 bit per pixel).

I would expect the whole thing to be 810 bytes long (5 bytes unidentified, 5 bytes escape sequence, 25 x 32 bytes of pixel data). I don't quite understand why it works with 796.

**Update:**

To convert a UIImage into the raw black and white data (without the escape sequence), the following code should help. I hope 1 bit per pixel bitmaps are still supported.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
size_t bytesPerRow = (uiImage.size.width + 7) / 8;
size_t imageDataSize = uiImage.size.height * bytesPerRow;
unsigned char* imgData = (unsigned char*) malloc(imageDataSize);
CGContextRef context =  CGBitmapContextCreate(imgData,
    uiImage.size.width, uiImage.size.height, 
    1, bytesPerRow, 
    colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[uiImage drawInRect: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, uiImage.size.width, uiImage.size.height)];
UIGraphicsPopContext();

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

for (int i = 0; i < imageDataSize; i++)
    imgData[i] = ~imgData[i];

... send the image (imgData) to the printer ...

free(imgData);
```

Comment: I agree the size of the array should be 810. I think the last 14 bytes of the image are white and their absence does not interfere with printing the static image. Now I just need to figure out how to convert a UIImage into hex array with one byte per pixel in black and white.

Comment: @FrankGibbs: I've updated my answer. The code might help you to convert the UIImage.

Comment: does this error mean 1 bit per pixel bitmaps are no longer supported? <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 1 integer bits/component; 1 bits/pixel; 1-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNone; 25 bytes/row.

Comment: @FrankGibbs: I'm afraid so. Do you really need a UIImage as an intermediate representation? Where's the image originally coming from?

Comment: It's a finger drawn image on a UIImageView.

Comment: @FrankGibbs: Then you'll have to create a gray-scale bitmap context (8 bits per component) and then convert it manually to a 1 bit image by stuffing each group of 8 consecutive pixels (8 bytes) into 1 byte.

Comment: ok, I'll see if I can find an example on how to do that. thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Its easiest to start with a black and white image (I used .png) 4 bytes are allocated to each pixel, the data of which you can get by using CgContextRef and CgContextDrawImage (I used the CGBitmapContextCreate method to populate an array of pixel data as well as create a black and white image from the edited data array. I averaged the rgb values for each pixel and then changed all pixel values to black or white (alpha == 255) depending on the average of rgb's.

Then you need to package every 8 pixels into 1 print byte (thus for a pixel of 4 bytes, look at a set of 32 bytes in the data array and set the binary values of the print byte on or off depending on whether a pixel is black (add pow(2, 7 - (position of pixel in 8 pixel sequence) ) or white (do nothing).

I converted a .png image to black and white .png and then to binary and printed the values on my screen. Try to keep the width of your .png in multiples of 8 or you'll have trouble (since you need to convert 8 bytes into 1 byte.

Comment: I don't have a working example yet. This is one of many projects I'm working on. Once I have a working example I'll post it.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I'm still figuring out how to convert images to a byte array. If I have any news, I'll post it as well.

Comment: I've added what I've managed to work out so far. Here's a link to the code I have so far that converts an image to the format needed by the p25i printer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838283/how-to-convert-image-to-bitmap-code-for-bluetooth-print-in-iphone/14278638#14278638